# initializeApp firebase issue

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

expo managed app user (latest versions)... we have this file for firebase.js and CANNOT figure out why we keep seeing the error

Need to see what is wrong in this file... if anything - it's driving me nuts! appreciate any feedback/tips

ERR:
12:03
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import Constants from "expo-constants"
import "@react-native-firebase/auth"
// Should not be used elsewhere in the project

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration -- from firebase console
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
databaseURL: Constants.manifest.extra.databaseURL,
projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId,
measurementId: Constants.manifest.extra.measurementId,
}

// Initialize Firebase
const Firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const firestore = getFirestore();

export default [Firebase, firestore]
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using SDK**
Make sure you have all the SDK's required for each firebase service you are using,

Most importantly the app SDK which should be listed first

**else**

import firebase and *initialize first*

this page should solve your problem :https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup#node.js-apps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for this! i noticed i was importing firebase on my app.tsx file and that resolved the error when i removed it